# Visual Studio, Server Explorer Cannot Establish Connection to Microsoft SQL server

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

[image]I have installed VS Community 2015 and try to establish connection to a SQL Server that is installed locally in my pc. When I try to connect to the SQL Server via Data Connection in the Server Explorer, it does not connect.
Any suggestion?`<add name="BaseDB" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Server=OLDKGL202146;Database=XXXXXXXXXX;User id=test;pwd=fatboy;Connection Timeout=60" />
  </connectionStrings>`
that is how my connection sting looks like and the SQL DB looks from SQL Management Studio.

[image]

Comment: any error messages? screen shots?

Comment: Can you connect to SQL Server using SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: At a guess you might have forgotten to put the instance name e.g. \SQLEXPRESS after the server name. I do that all the time!

Comment: if you can connect in SSMS, look in the logs to see the errors as to why VS isnt connecting

Comment: Server Explorer has nothing to do with web.config or app.config. It's works the same as SSMS. The connection string you posted doesn't help. *Did* you enter the same settings as in SSMS? Did you use the `Test Connection` button to test the connection? Was there an error? Post the *actual* error. If you want to post a screenshot, post a screenshot of the `Add Connection` dialog

Comment: Try this one -- (make changes accordingly) 
<add name="Employee" connectionString="Server=OLDKGL202146; Database=TSQL; UID=sa; Password=password_123; Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: I added screenshot to how it looks from VS when I try to connect the SQL server via VS. it works fine with windows Authintication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you enable the mixed mode authentication?

Did you restart SQL services after changing the mixed mode authentication?

Start - > View Local Services -> SQL Server(SQLEXPRESS) > restart it

Some of the server level properties takes only after a SQL restart , one such is authentication modes.

Comment: I enabled the mixed authentication mode from SSMS  right click on server --> Security. then change server authenitcation from windows to SQL server and Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Through Sql server management studio make sure what kind of Authentication is being used and that you can login from SSMS.
If you can't login even with SSMS open Configuration Manager and in services make sure your instance (for ex. SQLEXPRESS) is Running. If not then restart the service.
And then try connecting to the server via Visual studio.